# Best practices for adding .env-File to Docker-Image during build in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, environment-variables

I have a node.js Project which I run as Docker-Container in different environments (local, stage, production) and therefor configure it via `.env`-Files. As always advised I don't store the `.env`-Files in my remote repository which is Gitlab. My production- and stage-systems are run as kubernetes cluster.

What I want to achieve is an automated build via Gitlab's CI for different environments (e.g. stage) depending on the commit-branch (named stage as well), meaning when I push to origin/stage I want an Docker-image to be built for my stage-environment with the corresponding `.env`-File in it.

On my local machine it's pretty simple, since I have all the different `.env`-Files in the root-Folder of my app I just use this in my `Dockerfile`

```
COPY .env-stage ./.env
```

and everything is fine.

Since I don't store the .env-Files in my remote repo, this approach doesn't work, so I used Gitlab CI Variables and created a variable named `DOTENV_STAGE` of type `file` with the contents of my local `.env-stage` file.

Now my problem is: How do I get that content as .env-File inside the docker image that is going to be built by gitlab since that file is not yet a file in my repo but a variable instead?

I tried using `cp` (see below, also in the `before_script`-section) to just copy the file to an `.env`-File during the build process, but that obviously doesn't work.

My current build stage looks like this:

```
image: docker:git

services:
  - docker:dind

build stage:
  only:
    - stage
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - cp $DOTENV_STAGE .env
    - docker pull $GITLAB_IMAGE_PATH-$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH || true
    - docker build --cache-from $GITLAB_IMAGE_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --file=Dockerfile-$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -t $GITLAB_IMAGE_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
    - docker push $GITLAB_IMAGE_PATH/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

This results in

```
 Step 12/14 : COPY .env ./.env
 COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder513570233/.env: no such file or directory
```

I also tried `cp $DOTENV_STAGE .env` as well as `cp $DOTENV_STAGE $CI_BUILDS_DIR/.env` and `cp $DOTENV_STAGE $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.env` but none of them worked.

So the part I actually don't know is: Where do I have to put the file in order to make it available to docker during build?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research I stumbled upon a support-forum entry on gitlab.com, which exactly describes my situation (unfortunately it got deleted in the meanwhile) and it got solved by the same approach I was trying to use, namely this:

```
...
script:
- cp $DOTENV_STAGE $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.env
...
```

in my .gitlab-ci.yml

The part I was actually missing was adjusting my `.dockerignore`-File accordingly (removing `.env` from it) and then removing the line

```
COPY .env ./.env
```

from my `Dockerfile`

**An alternative approach** I thought about after [joyarjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357756/5168701) could be to use a [ConfigMap for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/). But I didn't try it yet

Comment: The support forum entry link seems dead, can you update it ?

Comment: @Nicolas I had to remove the link since the post was not there anymore

Answer (score 7):

You should avoid copying `.env` file into the container altogether. Rather feed it from outside on runtime. There's a dedicated prop for that: [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).

```
web:
  env_file:
    - .env
```

You can store contents of the `.env` file itself in a [Masked Variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#masked-variables) in the GitLabs CI backend. Then dump it to `.env` file in the runner and feed to Docker compose pipeline.

Comment: OK, thanks, but this leads to more questions. First of all I'm not using docker-compose. I use a kubernetes-cluster where I run the containers. And to be honest, I'd rather put my env inside the image instead of the kubectl yml-FIles, since those are commited to gitlab. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I believe there should be a similar mechanism available. Not an expert there, sorry.

Comment: I have the same issue with GCP Cloud Run not loading ENVs. @jayarjo Why is it better not to put .env file in the image?

Comment: Because if someone grabs the image, she will have access to all of your secrets.